# Pasting Values in Excel not Formulas from a Macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros, formulas

I currently have a macro that copies data from one sheet and archives it in another sheet. The issue that I have is that it is copying and pasting the formulas and it need to copy and paste values only.

```
Sub Archive_Execution()

Dim mainworkbook As Workbook
Set mainworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Dim rangeName
Dim strDataRange As Range
Dim keyRange As Range

rangeName = "Archive_Execution"
Application.Goto Reference:=rangeName
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Archive Execution").Activate
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
mainworkbook.Sheets("Archive Execution").Paste

Sheets("Archive Execution").Activate
Set strDataRange = Range("A2:AA1000000")
Set keyRange = Range("D1")
strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlAscending

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated on tweaking my code so that only values are pasted not formulas

Comment: Technically all you need to do is replace `mainworkbook.Sheets("Archive Execution").Paste` with `mainworkbook.Sheets("Archive Execution").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` but I'd recommend rethinking your code to avoid using `Select`, `Copy` and `Paste`. Instead you can just set the cells in the new worksheet to the values you are importing.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried including .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues but I get an error of PasteSpecial method of Worksheet class failed? Please could you expand on what you mean by setting the cells in the new worksheet to the values?

Comment: Sorry, you would need to specify the range you are pasting to, at the moment you are only specifying the worksheet. Try: `Sheets("Archive Execution").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments use `Range().PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` if you want to copy only values.

I also recommend using the `Intersect` method and `Worksheets("").UsedRange` to trim down your ranges.

```
Sub Archive_Execution()

    Dim strDataRange As Range
    Dim keyRange As Range

    With Sheets("Archive Execution")
        Range("Archive_Execution").Copy
        .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    With Sheets("Archive Execution")
        Set strDataRange = Intersect(.Range("A2:AA" & .Rows.Count), .UsedRange)
        Set keyRange = .Range("D1")
        strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlAscending
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does copy and paste the values across but  on the mainworkbook.Sheets("Archive Execution").Paste line, I get the error  'object required'

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using Copy and Paste you can try something like the following, much faster than copy pasting.

```
Sub Archive_Execution()

    Dim mainworkbook As Workbook, rangeName
    Dim strDataRange As Range, keyRange As Range
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

    Set mainworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    rangeName = "Archive_Execution"
    r = Range(rangeName).Rows.Count
    c = Range(rangeName).Columns.Count

    With Sheets("Archive Execution").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .Resize(r, c) = Range(rangeName).Value
    End With

    Sheets("Archive Execution").Activate
    Set strDataRange = Range("A2:AA1000000")
    Set keyRange = Range("D1")
    strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlAscending

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to resize the range to fit the new data using that technique.

Comment: True, edited the answer as an alternative to copy and pasting.

Comment: Each range inside `Sheets("Archive Execution").Range()` needs to be qualified to reference `Sheets("Archive Execution")` and it would be cleaner to use resize.  Would you mind if I edited your answer?

Comment: Technically I should have qualified `Rows.Count` to the worksheet but it won't cause an issue unless your working with an Excel 2003 workbook or older version from an Excel 2007 or later version workbook.